# Convert ctrl A delimited file to csv

Tags: linux, excel, export-to-csv, csv

I have a `ctrl+A` delimited file with `.txt` extension.

I would like to convert this file into a CSV file. The ONLY tool available to me is Excel and each file is about 200MB.

Comment: Whar is the actual **ASCII** code for the delimiter ??

Comment: Thanks. It is ASCII 1.

Comment: Nope, that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on linux, you can use sed:

```
cat file_with_asv.txt | sed -e 's/\x01/,/g' > new_file.csv
```

If you're on Mac OS X, their version of sed doesn't like \x01.  Instead, you can use the following syntax, but to get the ^A character, you can literally hold ctrl and hit A.

```
cat file_with_asv.txt | sed -e 's/\^A/,/g' > new_file.csv
```